# PID controller best when no model of process available?

Tags: control, control-system, pid-controller

> While PID control is the best controller in an observer without a
>   model of the process... (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller#Limitations_of_PID_control)

What is this supposed to mean? Or more correctly, what would be a proof that PID controller indeed is the best controller when a model of process is not available?

Comment: I think they just mean that when you don't have a model, you don't have too much choice of control strategies, so you might as well try PID.

Answer (score 1):

PID is quite flexible and can be tuned for many situations. 
This makes it suitable in most cases. For problems with no clear workflow for finding a solution, a PID control loop can offer a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Claiming PID, or any particular control scheme, is the "best" when you don't know much about the process is wrong.

I think what that quote is trying to say is that since PID is quite flexible and relatively easily implemented in various ways, it's a reasonable choice when you don't know much about the system you are trying to control.  The result may not be optimal, but with enough tweaking, you should be able to get a PID controller to control pretty much anything.

Claiming a particular method is "best" in this case is wrong.  To decide bestness, there need to be criteria to measure different implementations by.  There are always tradeoffs.  What makes one controller better than another?  Low cost implementation, ease of implementation in analog hardware, ease of implementation in microcontroller firmware, fastest settling time to a new value within some error limit, etc?  PID or any one control scheme is not best across all possible criteria.  The statement you quote is therefore more religion than engineering, unless there are significant qualifiers to it that you haven't quoted.